# adding parameter to wordpress url without query string

Tags: regex, wordpress

i want to have parameter in friendly urls way, have done it with query string but this is not what i want

below is my link

http://www.example.org/category-name/sub-category/post-name-goes-here

and want to have link in template like this

http://www.example.org/category-name/sub-category/post-name-goes-here/parameter

it should still load the same single page but with parameter so i can use condition in single page template

how i can ignore this using rewrite rule or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a rewrite rule so it doesnt try and "solve" the url address using its standard function .

See my previous answers here:

[Add "custom page" without page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238480/add-custom-page-without-page/25239381#25239381)

[WordPress Rewrite based on form hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786458/wordpress-rewrite-based-on-form-hidden-field/26792176#26792176)

you can pretty much add anything to the url after that.

Comment: is there any .htaccess rewrite solution ?

Comment: yes same thing, but better to use the WP version rather than manually adding rules?